# Resize/Scale controls in paper js like in fabric js

Tags: javascript, paperjs

my question is is there someone out there who managed to get a scaling/resizing like this: http://fabricjs.com/controls but in paper js?

Would appreciate some help or directions how to do that.

EDIT: You see the quadrats in the link, when you pull them the object gets sized in that direction. For example when I pull right side then only right side of object is expanded (in other word the object is scaled horizontally).
That behavior I'm looking for, when I pull an object on one side then it should expand in that side AND I also want to do that when the object have some rotation (e.g. 20° from x axis)

Comment: you should add the specific code you're interested in to your question

Comment: Hi, thanks for commenting I will change that accordingly. But I don't have code right now but I will update my question so people will understand what I mean

Answer (score 1):

You have to listen to a slider change event, then update your item size accordingly.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tary9kx4/) demonstrating the solution.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Debug Paper.js</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.11.8/paper-full.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        html,
        body {
            margin   : 0;
            overflow : hidden;
            height   : 100%;
        }

        canvas[resize] {
            width  : 100%;
            height : 100%;
        }

        div {
            position : fixed;
            top      : 15px;
            left     : 15px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" resize></canvas>
<div>
    <p>move the slider and see the circle scale change</p>
    <input type="range" min="1" max="5" step="0.5" value="1">
</div>
<script>
    // setup paper
    paper.setup('canvas');

    // draw a circle
    const circle = new paper.Path.Circle({
        center: paper.view.center,
        radius: 50,
        fillColor: 'orange',
        // make sure matrix is not applied so we can easily use scaling property
        applyMatrix: false
    });

    // on slider value change
    $('input').change(function() {
        const value = $(this).val();
        // update circle scale
        circle.scaling = value;
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying but the thing is you see in your example you are scaling the whole object, I only want for example to change the width or height :) So thats not exactly what I'm looking for. Please check my link: http://fabricjs.com/controls you see the quadrats on the side of the object when you pull them then the object gets expanded in that direction